# Append URL variable to window.history.back();

Tags: javascript, php

I have a form with a captcha...

If captcha is entered wrong, I need to go back to form page and let the user know he/she has to try again.

I want to use `window.history.back` as the form fields will still have the values which were entered.

Is it possible to append a variable to the url when I use this JS method?

I can't use `window.location = document.referer` because it doesn't retain field values.

Any ideas?

Comment: Check the captcha using ajax. Then you don't need to worry about it.

Comment: Check this out: https://gist.github.com/zaus/4717416